# OpenGL inter-process GPU resource sharing

Tags: c++, opengl, directx, ipc

So MSDN says that you can share resources (heaps) between two processes:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt186623(v=vs.85).aspx

Is the same thing possible in OpenGL? If so, I could use some function names or any kind of starting point for my search since I haven't found anything yet.

Note that I am trying to avoid copying the data to the system memory and back to the same device, as this would be the most trivial approach to solving this.

Comment: Do you want to share GPU memory with two different process' or share GPU memory with several threads or with several apps or what?

Comment: I want to share the GPU memory between two different processes (UE4 and my custom <DirectX or OpenGL> app). Lowering latency is my primary concern.

Answer (score 0):

Generally GPU resources (textures, shaders, etc.) are bound by their contexts. Contexts are then bound to their parent processes. There are methods of sharing data between OpenGL contexts on Windows (see wglShareList), but it can be difficult.

You may want to look into instead just using multiple contexts. If you must share data between contexts, you can use PBOs to asynchronously copy data from GPU -> CPU (other methods of copying texture data block CPU/parent process) and then copy it back to the other context. Inefficient, but there is no easy way of doing this.

Comment: Shared gl-contexts is not difficult at all. Most APIs (GLFW, SDL. etc) just require a proper flag in the context/window creation. And they share most of GPU RAM buffers and programs.

Comment: True, but not between parent processes, just between "Windows": http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/context_guide.html. OP asked about sharing GPU resources *between processes*, not within the same process.

Comment: Make shared context. As UE4 is open sourced ,you can dig into GL module and even see how they do it. Yes, UE4 itself uses more than one context in the rendering API

Answer (score 0):

This is possible on Windows using NV_DX_Interop extension to share OpenGL data with D3D and then using D3D resource sharing.

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure about across process but you can share context between two different thread and by sharing opengl context you can create the resource and share it with thread.

for reference see

[OpenGL Multithreading Sharing Context](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_and_multithreading)